# Extracting values to points using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I'm still a beginner in using ArcGIS. I'm using ArcMap version 10.8.1.

I'm currently working on habitat use analysis for my thesis. My data consists of coordinates (latitude, longitude) obtained from GPS collars from animals. My goal is to draw a distribution graph which will represent where the animal has been in relation to different objects (from now on I will just use forest, because this is one of them). I have a TIF file for my country that has specified distances to forest for each point on the map, so for each location. This file is in MGI 1901 Slovene National Grid coordinate system. When I added my coordinates as a layer I set the coordinate system to 4326 WGS 1984 - because when I set this one, coordinates align with my TIF file, if I try to set the same one as my TIF file, the coordinates and the TIF file do not align.

Firstly I exported the coordinate data and created a shapefile with which I continued to work. Then I used Spatial Analyst Tools - Extraction - Extract Values to Points (as suggested by my mentor). I then created a new file which I exported to excel and from the raster values that I obtained I created a histogram. These raster values are in m, so for example if I have a value 100, this means that the animal was located 100 m from forest for that particular location.

My question is regarding these raster values that I obtained. It seems strange to me that the variation between the different values is so small. The majority of the values are 0, 100 or 200, all round values. This kind of makes sense, since the animal spend the majority of the time in the forest (0 m), or in its near proximity (100 or 200 m), but there are also odd values, which have decimals, for example: 223.607 and 360.555. And these exact same values are then at least doubled for different locations. I find it weird that all these odd values are at least in pairs (or more) and that there aren't any other values with different decimals.

I only know this one way to obtain these values needed to create a histogram, since it was suggested by my mentor, and I am just not sure if the values are supposed to be of so little variety. I am also adding a picture of some of my values.

[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question and add some images of what you have and why you think they are erroneous, currently your question is too rambling to focus on the problem.

Comment: You need to give a lot more information (like the projection system of all your data and the exact steep you use to get those value) if you want to get meaningful answer

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Extract values to point interpolated between neighboring points, try sample instead.

Comment: Thank you, if I check this box the values come out totally different and variable and also all of them are now in decimals. I hope this is the correct way and that my values are correct now. Thank you very much for your help. Can you please explain how come this makes such a difference? I don't exactly understand the process behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is much improved but is still missing important information such as resolution of your distance raster. That said your source data for your GPS collar data is in WGS84, thats why you needed to set it to WGS84 so the GIS knows how to plot it against your raster which is the Slovene National Grid coordinate system.

Once you have your GPS plotting correctly, **project** (not export)  that into a new shapefile with the output coordinate system set to Slovene National Grid. You should then have 2 datasets your distance raster and new GPS data plotting correctly and both in Slovene National Grid coordinate system. Top tip start a new map with these datasets to ensure this is correct.

You can then use the extract values tool.

You may be getting double values as your GPS data has stacked points or that you have multiple points within a single raster cell, because your animal did not move very far.

You may be getting decimal numbers instead of integer values because either the raster is like that or you are interpolating, read help on the [tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm).